# How can I scrapy the stock information of this <selfridges.com> website without selenium?

Tags: python, web-crawler

website URL: https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/cat/giorgio-armani-lip-mastero-mattr-6-6ml_317-77011643-LB014200/

I can get the file which contain price information and stock information through `chrome -> F12 -> network -> XHR`.

price API url:
https://www.selfridges.com/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/price/byId/317-77011643-LB014200

stock API url:
https://www.selfridges.com/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/stock/byId/317-77011643-LB014200

And I can get the response content by directly visiting the API link like this:

```py
s= requests.session()
response = s.get(price_api_url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

However, for stock URL, this method will not work, and a `403 Forbidden` status code will be returned.

I've tried using cookies, but as same result.

The same effect even if accessed through chrome browser.

Maybe useful information：

I get the source code which contain API method, but I can not find the `{variantValue}` and `{variantName}`.

```
"@data_api":"
    {"apiKeyValue":"xjut2p34999bad9dx7y868ng",
     "apiKey":"Api-Key",
     "withCredentials":true,
     "priceApi":"/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/price/byId/{partNumber}",
     "stockApi":"/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/stock/byId/{partNumber}?option\u003d{variantName}\u0026optionValue\u003d{variantValue}",
     "cacheControl":"no-cache",
     "addToWishListApiUrl":"/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/wishlist",
     "addToBagApiUrl":"/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/cart"
}"
```

Comment: in `Chrome` you should check want else it sends - maybe it need special headers - like special header for XHR request. OR maybe you have to first GET main page to get fresh cookies.

Comment: Firefox has similar tool like Chrome and it has "Copy reuqest as CURL command" and using this command in console I can get stock data. Using [https://curl.trillworks.com/](https://curl.trillworks.com/) I can convert tCURL o Python `requests` and it also can get stock but I don't know how long server will respect this code and its cookies. It may need fresh cookies when I run it later.

Comment: I'm sorry, My question has been solved now by your answer. Do I need confirm that this question has been answered on stackoverflow? and how to ? I'm new one to stackoverflow. @furas

Comment: Here is place for comment and you can't confirm it as answer. But I put it below as answer and then you can mark it as accepted and you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Chrome`/`Firefox` you should check what else it sends - maybe it needs special headers - like special header for XHR request (`'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`). OR maybe you have to first `GET` main page to get fresh cookies.

`Firefox` has similar tool like `Chrome` and it has `"Copy reuqest as CURL command"` and using this command in console I can get stock data.

```
curl 'https://www.selfridges.com/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/stock/byId/317-77011643-LB014200' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' -H 'Api-Key: xjut2p34999bad9dx7y868ng' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/cat/giorgio-armani-lip-mastero-mattr-6-6ml_317-77011643-LB014200/' -H 'Cookie: AWSELB=85FF15BB10593ECE847219C9B214EEC5BBD393B7301D90E17B625C66620D7473C3FCE779E5EA1D351A2192C6C975C128815AC60F1118B8968E03001896493C045071A25E98; SF_COUNTRY_LANG=GB_en; COOKIE_NOTICE_SEEN=seen; utag_main=v_id:016df6fcb41700231568089828b001044006200900c48$_sn:1$_ss:0$_pn:2%3Bexp-session$_st:1571808694713$ses_id:1571806819351%3Bexp-session; utag_chan={"channel":"","channel_set":"","channel_converted":false,"awc":""}; Apache=10.77.3.197.1571806819436981; JSESSIONID=0000FBk5q2nb8WGtpDUjLBiNvha:17re3pp2r; WC_PERSISTENT=EBTewrGMk86bvcN%2fwqrCZtv%2bnXk%3d%0a%3b2019%2d10%2d23+05%3a00%3a22%2e442%5f1571806819438%2d1407831%5f10052%5f1480243004%2c%2d1%2cGBP%5f10052; WC_SESSION_ESTABLISHED=true; WC_ACTIVEPOINTER=%2d1%2c10052; WC_AUTHENTICATION_1480243004=1480243004%2cQbYKoQJpwYcMM6iznWYL1ludFS8%3d; WC_USERACTIVITY_1480243004=1480243004%2c10052%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cpfXMuSmw4%2b86xW7eYpU03lFrlirAydf27cytgnreiETU0zdlaTYkdIvAFHFrHmqcOVjtNhcyBowU%0ah%2bD2jUFBMXetfiZdIXQuaegcWHNNUqlIHSvMQrpghGvwCVdLsi%2bVK5UuT9NrO2L6RLVuf2ROuIXl%0avrgeD6slXh2C9RTk%2fKYkbRFJrqWGbiO5BZCmcHU14xftVA%3d%3d; cmTPSet=Y; CoreID6=87385145971315718068242&ci=90262645; 90262645_clogin=v=7&l=62021491571806824206&e=1571808675410; SIGNUP_POPUP_SEEN=seen' -H 'DNT: 1'
```

Using https://curl.trillworks.com/ I can convert `CURL` to Python `requests` and it also can get stock.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'AWSELB': '85FF15BB10593ECE847219C9B214EEC5BBD393B7301D90E17B625C66620D7473C3FCE779E5EA1D351A2192C6C975C128815AC60F1118B8968E03001896493C045071A25E98',
    'SF_COUNTRY_LANG': 'GB_en',
    'COOKIE_NOTICE_SEEN': 'seen',
    'utag_main': 'v_id:016df6fcb41700231568089828b001044006200900c48$_sn:1$_ss:0$_pn:2%3Bexp-session$_st:1571808694713$ses_id:1571806819351%3Bexp-session',
    'utag_chan': '{"channel":"","channel_set":"","channel_converted":false,"awc":""}',
    'Apache': '10.77.3.197.1571806819436981',
    'JSESSIONID': '0000FBk5q2nb8WGtpDUjLBiNvha:17re3pp2r',
    'WC_PERSISTENT': 'EBTewrGMk86bvcN%2fwqrCZtv%2bnXk%3d%0a%3b2019%2d10%2d23+05%3a00%3a22%2e442%5f1571806819438%2d1407831%5f10052%5f1480243004%2c%2d1%2cGBP%5f10052',
    'WC_SESSION_ESTABLISHED': 'true',
    'WC_ACTIVEPOINTER': '%2d1%2c10052',
    'WC_AUTHENTICATION_1480243004': '1480243004%2cQbYKoQJpwYcMM6iznWYL1ludFS8%3d',
    'WC_USERACTIVITY_1480243004': '1480243004%2c10052%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cpfXMuSmw4%2b86xW7eYpU03lFrlirAydf27cytgnreiETU0zdlaTYkdIvAFHFrHmqcOVjtNhcyBowU%0ah%2bD2jUFBMXetfiZdIXQuaegcWHNNUqlIHSvMQrpghGvwCVdLsi%2bVK5UuT9NrO2L6RLVuf2ROuIXl%0avrgeD6slXh2C9RTk%2fKYkbRFJrqWGbiO5BZCmcHU14xftVA%3d%3d',
    'cmTPSet': 'Y',
    'CoreID6': '87385145971315718068242&ci=90262645',
    '90262645_clogin': 'v=7&l=62021491571806824206&e=1571808675410',
    'SIGNUP_POPUP_SEEN': 'seen',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Api-Key': 'xjut2p34999bad9dx7y868ng',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/cat/giorgio-armani-lip-mastero-mattr-6-6ml_317-77011643-LB014200/',
    'DNT': '1',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.selfridges.com/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/stock/byId/317-77011643-LB014200', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print(response.text)
```

But I don't know how long server will respect this code and its cookies. It may need fresh cookies when I will run it later.

---

**EDIT:** After few hours the same code still gives me data. Sometimes I can get result even with only

```
import requests

headers = { 'Api-Key': 'xjut2p34999bad9dx7y868ng' }

response = requests.get('https://www.selfridges.com/api/cms/ecom/v1/GB/en/stock/byId/317-77011643-LB014200', headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

but sometimes it gives me `<h1>Developer Inactive</h1>` so I'm note sure if it is not a temporary problem on server.